# From which git repos does the Ubuntu Cloud Archive compile its packages?

Tags: git, cloud, openstack

The [Ubuntu Cloud Archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive#The_Ubuntu_Cloud_Archive) "gives users the ability to install newer releases of OpenStack on an Ubuntu LTS release (only) as they become available up through to the next Ubuntu LTS release."

I'm looking at a version of Qemu from this archive, specifically version `1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10~cloud0`. Note that the cloud archive versions have `~cloud` at the end. You can find these packages [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-cloud-archive/+archive/ubuntu/ussuri-staging/+packages) (you need to click 'next' several times to reach qemu; all packages are built for bionic).

You can't seem to get the `debian` tar file or the `.dsc` file from there, but you can see it [here](http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/): [this file](http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu_4.2-3ubuntu6.10%7Ecloud0.dsc).
It contains (amongst other things) this:

```
Vcs-Browser: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu
Vcs-Git: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu
```

This however seems to be the source for the normal Ubuntu packages. It doesn't contain version `4.2-3ubuntu6.7~cloud0`, only `4.2-3ubuntu6.7`, and that is a version in the `ubuntu/focal-updates` branch (and not bionic).

I tried to rebuild that version nevertheless on a bionic VM, but it failed due to various reasons (not all dependencies could be installed because the required version was too high, or it didn't exist at all). Even after hacking around those, compilation ended with some error, which told me that there must be additional patches somewhere, that allow the cloud archive to offer a version that runs on bionic.

Indeed, one can look at the [`debian` tar file](http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu_4.2-3ubuntu6.10%7Ecloud0.debian.tar.xz). It contains more patches than can be found in the git repository I located above.

One might think that [https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-cloud-archive/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+git/qemu](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-cloud-archive/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+git/qemu) is what I'm looking for, but this has had no updates since 2016.

This is about how far I got. Where is the upstream source for this Qemu version really located? I am also interested in the same question for other OpenStack components, but I hope that the answer is the same.

(I have also asked this question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297435/from-which-git-repos-does-the-ubuntu-cloud-archive-compile-its-packages), because I am not sure of the best place to ask about this)

ETA: over at askubuntu the question was deleted after some time because nobody could answer it... that's also a way to handle difficult questions.